# Calculate The average height of presidents where x is start of slice and y is end of slice and z is average

Tags: python

Create a program, presidents.py, that takes two arguments. These arguments will correspond to the start and stop of a slice, respectively. It will slice the heights column in the president_heights.csv files.

```py
x = input("Enter first number:")
y = input("Enter second number:")
result = df.iloc[:x,y].mean(axis=0) print(result)
```

Getting error:

`Location based indexing can only have \[integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array\] types`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the input to an int

```
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
```

Comment: When i added the input to in; i am getting this error now:- IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds